# External third party API related to Entities in a DDD way

Tags: php, entity, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a new project where we will use DDD. The problem here arises on how to approach a case where an external API in my opinion is very related to one entity itself.

Imagine the entity Card. Every user can have a card, similar to a bank plastic card, and that card needs to be created, activated, charged, etc.

The problem here is that this card is related to an external API that manages the card creation, refund, activation and so on.

In a code way without thinking in the infrastructure I see this way.

```
new Card();
$card->isActive();
$card->refund();
```

Etc.

But the thing is that this entity functions needs to contact with an external API that really creates all that actions. But for me it looks like infrastructure and is something outside of the Domain Model itself.

Is it correct in a DDD point of view that this entities are capable of connect to the API and make the calls to the API inside?

Isn't it close to DDD to use a service that does some king of:

```
$service->activateCard($card);
```

Then what happens to the $card->activate() methods that seemed so natural to me in the ubiquitous language?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you end up finding a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Domain events come to mind. You could have `Card` emit `CardActivated`, `CardRefunded` events with associated data. They would be handled by an infrastructure service that knows how to talk to the external API, leaving your domain layer happily unaware of the technical details.

Comment: The only thing I could see is that you would have to process the events in the same transaction as the one used to persist the AR. Also, I believe that an alternative approach such as calling on the cardService from the application service or passing an ICanRefund service object to the card.refund() operation could make sense. PS: Haven't forgot to contact you, I just did not have time yet ;)

Comment: But is a good practice to inject services that are so Infrastructure dependant (3rd party API) to entities?

Comment: @JonathanGimeno Technically speaking, as long as these services are injected it's still loose coupling so I wouldn't call it bad practice. However, I feel that even better separation of concerns can be achieved if the domain entity has no knowledge of an external thing it must call after its entity job is done.